# subdomain.domain is redirecting to domain/subdomain

Tags: subdomain

Anyone know what is going on?

Here is my .htaccess file (only rewrite conf):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on



RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]



RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l



RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Did you check secure and unsecure url in database?

Comment: Savan, thanks for your response. Here is my conf: https://imgur.com/a/iLKPzb6. Translation tip: "Sim" means "Yes"

Comment: Actually, I don't think magento is doing this. I'm quite sure it was some mistake I did setting up apache2 I can't figure out. The problem is that I can't make radical changes like reinstall all services because I'm on an production server.